# Combine two for loops to change a key value in Python

Tags: python

I have a json that I convert in Python. I'd like to change a key value dependin on another key value.

A simple of json:

```
[{"id"= 1,
  "results":[{
    "image_url": "www.urlone.com",
    "urlcloud": "www.example.com/"
    },
    {
    "image_url": "www.urltwo.com,
    "urlcloud": "www.example.com"
    }],
  "images": [{
    "url": "www.urlone.com",
    "path": "123456.jpg"},
    {"url": "www.urlone.com",
     "path": "7891011.jpg"}]
 } ... ]
```

How to add the path to url_cloud if the image_url is the same ?

```
import json

with open('./input/test3.json', encoding='utf-8') as data_file:
    data = json.loads(data_file.read())

for i in data:
    results = i['results']
    images = i['images']

    for img in images:
        imgpath = img['path']
        imgurl = img['url']
        print(imgpath)

    for result in results:
        imgcloud = result['urlcloud']
        imageurl = result['image_url']
        if imgurl == imageurl:
            imgcloud = imgcloud + imgpath
            print(imgcloud)
```

Expected output of [{"id"= 1,

```
"results":[{
    "image_url": "www.urlone.com",
    "urlcloud": "www.example.com/123456"
    },
    {
    "image_url": "www.urltwo.com,
    "urlcloud": "www.example.com/7891011"
    }],
  "images": [{
    "url": "www.urlone.com",
    "path": "123456.jpg"},
    {"url": "www.urlone.com",
     "path": "7891011.jpg"}]
 } ... ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Iteratively:

```
data = [{"id": 1,
         "results": [{"image_url": "www.urlone.com", "urlcloud": "www.example.com/"},
                     {"image_url": "www.urltwo.com", "urlcloud": "www.example.com"}],
         "images": [{"image_url": "www.urlone.com", "path": "123456.jpg"},
                    {"image_url": "www.urlone.com", "path": "7891011.jpg"}]
         }]

urlclouds = []
for d in data:
    for res in d['results']:
        for img in d['images']:
            if res['image_url'] == img['image_url']:
                urlclouds.append(res['urlcloud'] + img['path'])

print(urlclouds)
```

The output:

```
['www.example.com/123456.jpg', 'www.example.com/7891011.jpg']
```

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear but I want to keep all of the structure and change the "url_cloud" but I unnderstand the logic, thanks !